# Waiting for localhost : getting this message on all browsers

Tags: localhost

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and have php5 and mysql installed. I have 3 web applications on my /var/www/html folder.  Until yesterday evening I was able to test and work on the applications.  All of a sudden, I am not able to load any of my applications on any of the browsers.  I have firefox and chrome installed.

I have checked the availability of MySQL and Apache.  Both are running correctly.  I have also restarted Apache.  I have cleared all the cookies and history from chrome and set it to default under chrome://flags.

After removing all the history and cookies from Chrome, I could load the first login page and when I provide the UID and password, I get `Waiting for localhost` and the page is stalled.

Of the three one of my smaller application loaded after 10 minutes, however a heavier application did not load at all.  However, the browser loads plain html files.

I have also tested on wifi, mobile internet dongle device and ethernet and there are no firewall issues. I have also cleared my machine's cache by

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean restart
```

None of this helped.  Can someone guide me on how do I resolve this?

Comment: run `wget -S --spider http://...` on one of the urls that redirects you to localhost and edit the output into your question. Edit your apache config into your question. If something redirects you to localhost it's either the apache config or one of the PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Check your hosts file for unnecessary entries.
/etc/hosts in Linux.
C:\Windows\drivers in Windows.

See if any other application is running on port 80.
Verify that your web app is returning a response to the client.
Check your database connection.

https://www.quora.com/Why-does-my-machine-keeps-waiting-for-localhost-forever